# Task scheduler doesn't work when select "Run whether user is logged in or not"

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, scheduled-tasks

We are using WebBrowser control to download a certain file in console application. We scheduled this console application in task scheduler with this selected option "Run only user is logged on", its working fine. But we scheduled this for "Run whether user is logged in or not". It will not work.
We couldn't see any error in command prompt. Can any faced this scenario?

Comment: is the machine turned on at the scheduled time? are there any errors, warnings or events on the event viewer around the time the task is supposed to run?

Comment: Try to add logging to your custom application and check the output

Comment: I couldn't see any errors, warning etc. When chose "Run only user is logged on", its only working in machine turned on, otherwise not working.

Comment: I've been doing some reading on this - how do you know the application is not running? if an application is set to run whether the user is logged in or not, no user interface will be displayed. See here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c03d6691-b058-4f8d-961c-e8eba25bbaed/task-scheduler-problem-run-whether-user-is-logged-on-or-not?forum=w7itprogeneral An easy proof of this would be to write to a logfile when the application is launched. If the file is created at the expected time, then the task scheduler is working correctly and the application is being run.

Comment: wait, hang on a second " *its only working in machine turned on, otherwise not working* "  - are you leaving the machine turned off at the scheduled time of the job?

Comment: Yes, when we select option "Run only user is logged on". If we turn off the machine, it will not work

Comment: I have the same problem. The app using WebBrowser control, fully automated (no user input required), but the app doing things like sendKeys to webBrowser control over Windows API. My guess that such API doesn't work in this mode. Again, I don't need TO SEE UI, just need automation to work.

Comment: Try changing the user to SYSTEM - also note it won't work for WSL it's intentionally sabotaged to utilize UI components so that it can't be run via task scheduler without the user logged on. (Confirmed using Powershell scripts echo'ing to a file on Windows 11 Pro)

Answer (score 2):

If an application is set to run whether the user is logged in or not, no user interface will be displayed. See here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c03d6691-b058-4f8d-961c-e8eba25bbaed/task-scheduler-problem-run-whether-user-is-logged-on-or-not?forum=w7itprogeneral

An easy proof of this would be to write to a logfile when the application is launched. If the file is created at the expected time, then the task scheduler is working correctly and the application is being run.

Regarding your comment below

> its only working in machine turned on, otherwise not working

If you have the machine turned off at the scheduled time of the task, it will not run. It can be logged out, but the machine does in fact need to be turned on. Your comment makes this seem like the cause.

Comment: All of this confusion goes back to 2010 and several thousand hours (included my past two days) have wasted since then just to figure out why this damn thing doesn't work the way it should be. Just because some selfish ignorant engineer in Microsoft have decided this way and supposed the users should know about this inconsistent behavior. **Don't be like that if you are designing any thing. Don't waste people's lives!** BTW, most windows programs don't function correctly if they run without user interface. For example if you schedule files to be downloaded in FDM it won't do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and I resolved the issue by the following steps.

1. Give only the file name in **Program/Script** field in actions tab and the path of your script in the **Start-in** field. In this way if you have any log files, Then you see that they are being created in the same directory.
2. When you say the script has to run even when user is not logged in, then the packages that you installed **specific for the user** cannot be used in your script
   For eg:
   If you have installed a python library for a specific user(i.e in C:\users folder) then you cannot use those packages in your python script that is going to be scheduled.